# Can you instantiate kendo-ui objects that are dynamically created after page load?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I've successfully used Kendo-UI widgets in a mobile app.  My current application, however, requires that I dynamically load and use various UI elements.  I've tried dynamically instantiating Kendo-UI widgets like this:

```
<ul id="my_ul" >
<script>$('#my_ul').kendoListView().style("inset");</script>
  <li>
    <label>Label 1:
      <input id="dynamicLI1" type="text" name="dynamicLI1" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Label 2:
      <input id="dynamicLI2" type="text" name="dynamicLI2" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This failed.  Is there a way to achieve this or something equivalent?  I really like Kendo-UI, but creating Kendo-UI objects after the `document.ready()` event is a must.

---

UPDATE 1
This is the code for updating the DOM

```
function request() {
  var url = "██████████████████████";
  $.post(url, {deviceUUID: device.uuid})
    .done( function(res) {
        if(res) {
            $("#dynamic").html(res);
        } else {
            alert("Login failed :(\n" + res);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert("post complete");
}
```

Comment: I am using KendoUI in a Cordova app.

Answer (score 1):

At the point your script is running, the `<li>` elements haven't been created yet.
Try moving the script tag until after your `</ul>`

```
<ul id="my_ul" >
  <li>
    <label>Label 1:
      <input id="dynamicLI1" type="text" name="dynamicLI1" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Label 2:
      <input id="dynamicLI2" type="text" name="dynamicLI2" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>$('#my_ul').kendoListView().style("inset");</script>
```

---

Is this HTML being dynamically added to the DOM somehow? You can also do something like:

```
// create new elements
var $list = $('<ul>...rest of html string...</ul>');
var $view = $('#myView');

// add elements to DOM
$view.append($list);

// init kendo list view
$list.kendoListView({
    style: inset
});
```

---

**Update 1**

You could also just rely on declarative widget initialization by doing this:

```
<ul id="my_ul" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" >
  <li>
    <label>Label 1:
      <input id="dynamicLI1" type="text" name="dynamicLI1" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Label 2:
      <input id="dynamicLI2" type="text" name="dynamicLI2" value="" />
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
    if(res) {
        $("#dynamic").html(res);
        kendo.bind($("#dynamic"), {}, kendo.mobile.ui);
    } else {
```

which should initialize any/all widgets and MVVM bindings declared in the HTML.

Comment: Your first suggestion seems to work.  Unfortunately when I do initialize the ul as a KendoUI object it no longer displays at all.  I'm not sure why that is.  I'm using it in a Cordova app.

Comment: Can you share more specific code? How are you adding the HTML to the DOM?

Comment: I updated the question.  Is there any other part of the code that would be useful?  Also, I'm using this in a Cordova application.

Comment: Your update doesn't seem to work either.  It displays the response without being initialized as a Kendo object.